# Colorbox is not showing content box correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a cbox that is not showing content as expected. It should show it as this image:

[image]

Instead, the inner box is not showing, but the scroll down is being done. The content is there, because I can see it in this image:

[image]

But it's not being shown inside the colorbox.

Any idea on why it's not working?

**EDIT:** As additional info, my *colorbox.css* is being loaded before the *colorbox.js*, and jquery is being loaded before *colorbox.js*.

After executing these lines:

```
 $('#cboxOverlay').css('z-index', '99');
 $('#cboxOverlay').show();
 optionsContainer.show();
```

The white box is being created with no content. But for the second example, the white box is not being shown...

Where *optionsContainer* contains text at *innerHTML* and *innerText*.

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is a really huge project. Even the content of the colorbox is being created dinamically due to some dinamyc vars. But the content and the problems are in the question. I feel it really hard to create a full working code snippet. I only need some ideas on why could it not be showing the box...

Comment: This is like showing a car that won't start and asking someone to find out why it won't work without touching it. You need to recreate a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Check your js console and tell us if you get some errors.

Comment: it seems there are some custom z-index overriding colorbox z-index.

Comment: just put the debuggers in code and debug in browser.

Comment: @AnkushJain you were right... I was overriding a css with z-index and box style... Please, answer the question so I can mark it as the correct one... thanks! :)

Comment: you are welcome @Sonhja :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some custom z-index overriding colorbox z-index.